# How To clear cache after logout In Laravel

Tags: google-chrome, caching, laravel-5

Its a common problem . When I logout and then click on the browser back button the browser shows the last loaded page from the website .

I have went through lots of links on stack most of them suggest to clear the headers on logout but it didn't worked .

here is the code that I have tried

```
Route::get('main/logout',function(){


 Session::flush();
 Auth::logout();
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
 header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
 header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
 session()->flash('alert-success', 'Success logged out');
 return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

**Update**

I also tried to add this in my APP.blade.php file in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

If any of you have any IDEA please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to include the following line on the page the user is getting back to, not the actual logout page:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

But this way you are loosing the advantage of browser caching, which in most cases is not a good thing to do. Just leave it be. The user can't interact with the server after logout anyway and only retrieves data he has already seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

Answer (score -1):

In your logout function clear the cache, put this code there

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

Comment: This is wildly incorrect as it clears the entire application cache, not the browser cache.